# Error using scaffolding in VS 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I am attempting to use the Scaffold feature in an ASP.NET Core application in Visual Studio 2017.  I'm using the MVC Controller with views, using Entity Framework.  I've set up a dbcontext and migration and used update-database to create a database.  I chose the "Minimal" scaffold option.  After choosing the model and dbcontext, when I click OK, I get a status dialog saying it is scaffolding, but that dialog exits with the error:

> Error There was an error running the selected code generator:
>   'Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load
>   file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Utils,
>   Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.
>   The system cannot find the file specified. at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design.Program.Main(String[]
>   args)'

I have made sure both Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Utils and Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design are referenced as packages in my project, though I'm not clear that is the right place for them. This is a new Azure VM with VS2017 Community pre-installed, latest updates, and no 3rd party add-ins, etc.  This error also occurrs scaffolding an empty view, so I'm fairly certain has nothing to do with EF.

How can I resolve this to get the scaffolding feature working?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this didn't fix the issue for me. Worth a try though.

I resolved it by loading the project in VS 2015, scaffolding the controller, saving it and then switching back to VS 2017.

Comment: did you needed the installation of some tolling for the VS 2015 to open the .NET Core project?

Comment: I already had the .net core tools installed before upgrading to VS2017 so I don't know whether it would have opened in VS2015 without the tools or not. I suspect not though.

Comment: So, your ASP.NET Core project was created with VS 2015? Because mine is created with VS 2017, so it does even not open in VS 2015...

Comment: No, it was created in VS 2017. I had no problem opening it in 2015 though.

Comment: I run a repair of the visual studio 2017 and the problem gone away

Answer (score 1):

The error about not being able to load Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Utils assembly is usually due to NuGet package cache or due to version mismatches of packages in the project.

Can you show your *.csproj* file?

A few things to try:

1. Ensure the package reference for the scaffolding packages Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design has the right version:
   a.  1.0.x for ASP.NET Core 1.0 and such.
2. Other scaffolding packages that shouldn’t be referenced directly are 
   a.  Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Utils
   b.  Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Templating
   c.  Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.EntityFrameworkCore
   d.  Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Core
   e.  Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration
   f.  Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.MsBuild
   g.  Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Contracts
   h.  Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc
   i.  Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools                        -- **This one needs to be a DotNetCliToolReference**
3. Clear the local NuGet cache.
4. Clear the bin and obj folders of the project and restore the project.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue and landed here trying to find the answer. Took me few more hours to figure it out though so posting here for anyone else who might find it helpful.

**Issue/Background:**
Even adding packages of CodeGeneration utils and design, the error remains there when generating the controller from VS2017. I created the project from command line and was working with VS Code before switching to VS2017.
Initially I got an the following error adding the controller:

[image]

For resolving this error I simply copied contents of project/bin/Debug to project/bin/MCD/Debug

After that the error went away. And that was the issue with the other error too. I added both packages after copying the above folder contents. The subsequent builds did not update the contents of this folder automatically, hence the error.

**Solution:**
Delete the bin folder and obj folders and rebuild. Then copy the contents of /bin/Debug to /bin/MCD/Debug (and also do the same for obj folder).

This resolved the issue for me.

Comment: Your error message is different, so the problem and the solution are different.

Answer (score 0):

Had exactly the same problem. Launched the visual studio installer and did a complete repair, selecting the ASP.net core development package. Now everything is working.