# How to solve "A processor named 'Scaffolding Assembly Loader' could not be found for the directive named 'ScaffoldingAssembly'" while adding a view?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, scaffolding

Can someone help me understand what this means, and what i can do to solve it?

> There was an error running the selected code generator 'Failed to
>   render template because of the following errors: "A processor named
>   'ScaffoldingAssemblyLoader' could not be found for the directive named
>   'ScaffoldingAssembly'. The transformation will not be run. The
>   following Exception was thrown: System.IO.FileNotFoundException:
>   Failed to resolve type for directive processor
>   ScaffoldingAssemblyLoader. at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.VSHost.TextTemplatingService.ResolveDi
>   (String processorName) at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.Engine.ProcessCustomDirectives
>   (ITextTemplatingEngineHost host, TemplateProcessingSession session,
>   lEnumerablel directivesToBeProcessed)' at line number '3' and column
>   number '3''.'

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43418091/error-using-scaffolding-in-vs-2017

from above link, you may try to repair vs 2017 or open solution in another VS like vs 2015. Such errors can caused by many things. so you have to carefully analyse your situation and act accordingly. with my experience i can say that try to open it in another vs first and the do repair if needed.

Comment: I had experienced the same thing. In my case, it was solved to repair Visual Studio from Visual Studio Installer. If it's helpful for you, I'll be happy.

Answer (score 1):

after creation of models and controllers you have to build your solution to scaffold views hope this will do the job